# pygame: Unable to forward songs with .wav extension

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

When I try to forward a song with .wav extension in pygame , I get an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\default\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\default\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 14, in forward
    pygame.mixer.music.play(start = forwarded_pos)
pygame.error: Position not implemented for music type
```

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame

root = Tk()
pygame.init()

def play():
    pygame.mixer.music.load("test.wav")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

def forward():
    forwarded_pos = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() + 10
    pygame.mixer.music.load("test.wav")
    pygame.mixer.music.play(start = forwarded_pos)

play_button = Button(root , text = "Play song" , command = play)
play_button.grid(row = 0 , column = 0)

forward_button = Button(root , text = "Forward song" , command = forward)
forward_button.grid(row = 1 , column = 0 , pady = 10)

mainloop()
```

As I was continuously getting that error , I tried this:

```
def forward():
    forwarded_pos = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() + 10
    pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(forwarded_pos)
```

But when I did that, I keep getting another error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\default\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\default\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 13, in forward
    pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(forwarded_pos)
pygame.error: set_pos unsupported for this codec
```

Is there any way to fix this problem?

I think forwarding is not supported in `.wav` format , so fixing this problem with any other format(**except** `.mp3`) will also be ok.

Comment: The docs seem to suggest using `OGG` format

Comment: I tried converting the file into .ogg format but I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Get_pos and set_pos are triggering the same errors for me. You actually don't need them as you can assign the forwarded_pos when you start playing the music as follows. This doesn't seem to work for .wav but it does for .ogg and .mp3 formats.

```
import pygame
from os import path

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.init()

snd_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "snd")
song = path.join(snd_dir, 'song_name.ogg')

forwarded_pos = 22

mixer = pygame.mixer.music
mixer.load(song)
mixer.play(-1, forwarded_pos)
# doesn't work for wav sounds types


while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Comment: Yes! This seems to work, but I having a problem loading .ogg files. I really have no idea why am I facing this issue, but it would be great if you could solve my problem. 
Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769088/pygame-error-not-an-ogg-vorbis-audio-stream